# asynchronous task angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to run an asynchronous task to check if is enabled or not mobile GPS device and also, to make a query to my web service. How to check the GPS and the connections to my webservice I have, but I have not found a way to make an asynchronous task within my controller. I'm working with ionic and angularjs

Comment: Umm ajax?  How about showing some code of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service which can be used to create promises and then wrap your service call within the promise something like:

```
$q.when(gpsServiceCheck.isEnabled()).then(function (result) {
    // Write your code to handle whatever isEnabled() would return.
});
```